# How to fix Manifest merger failed issue?

Tags: java, android

I got an error message like this.Can someone help me to solve this problem?

"Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0] C:\Users\Rusiru.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-auth-17.0.0.aar\2a8aa5604754dd2bbbd6d91f1ec6c173\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.auth" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)"

Here's my manifest

````
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.tinder_exp1">



    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>```


```   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'```
````

Comment: In your module's `build.gradle` file, raise `minSdkVersion` from 15 to 16.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did that and seems like i got no errors at all but i've got a red underline under this "implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' "

Answer (score 1):

Updated minSdkVersion to API level 16 from gradle

or downgrade your firebase version